# Ansible playbook to create Cloud SQL instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

I am using the following playbook to create a Cloud SQL instance and a DB, but I am getting the error that follows the playbook. I have tried to follow all indentations. Could anyone please help me figure where I am wrong?:

```
- name: 'Create Cloud SQL instance and DB'
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: false
  gather_facts: no
  # Roles & Tasks
  tasks:
  - name: create an instance
  gcp_sql_instance:
    name: "ansible_test"
    settings:
      ip_configuration:
        authorized_networks:
        - name: google dns server
          value: 8.8.8.8/32
      tier: db-n1-standard-1
    region: us-central1
    project: "imigcp"
    auth_kind: "serviceaccount"
    service_account_file: "~/ansible/imigcp-c6e2408b2978.json"
    state: present
  register: instance


  - name: create a database
    gcp_sql_database:
      name: test_object_ansible
      charset: utf8
      instance: "ansible_test"
      project: imigcp
      auth_kind: serviceaccount
      service_account_file: "~/ansible/imigcp-c6e2408b2978.json"
      state: present
```

**Error received is as follows:**

```
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: No JSON object could be decoded

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The error appears to be in '/home/kuwali_sarma/ansible/inventory/gcp_cloud_sql.yaml': line 27, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


  - name: create a database
  ^ here
```

I feel there is a syntax error somewhere, and I am not at all able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Figured the correct indentation by hit and trial. I'm learning Ansible and finindg it quite difficult to maintain correct indentation in playbooks. If anyone has any suggestion, please do provide!

```
---
- name: 'Create Cloud SQL instance and DB'
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  become: false
  gather_facts: no

  # Roles & Tasks
  tasks:
          
   - name: create an instance
     gcp_sql_instance:
         name: "ansibletest"
         settings:
           ip_configuration:
             authorized_networks:
             - name: google dns server
               value: 8.8.8.8/32
           tier: db-n1-standard-1
         region: us-central1
         project: "imigcp"
         auth_kind: "serviceaccount"
         service_account_file: "~/ansible/imigcp-c6e2408b2978.json"
         state: present
     register: instance
```

Comment: I am using Atom now for my playbooks and I am quite liking how it helps with the indentation.